# Handle signals in Perl

Tags: perl, signals

How could I write a program which handle such signals ?

- `SIGUSR1` - Print the statistic (like the `dd` utility does);
- `SIGUSR2` - Print the amount of free memory;
- `SIGINT` - Send `USR1` to itself and quit the program.

This is what I have and there is no output:

```
$| = 1;
kill 'USR1';
kill 'USR2';

$SIG{USR1} = {print `dd if=/def/zero of=/dev/null bs=512`};
$SIG{USR2} = {print `free -m`};
$SIG{INT}  = {kill 'USR1' => $$; die};
```

Comment: How are you trying to send these signals? What are you trying that you think will send them before execution reaches the end of the script and it just exits normally?

Comment: @Wooble, Thank you for your questions. I am very new at programming.
Don't know how to make it properly. I made some changes  in update, but still not working properly.

Comment: @sliddy want to edit your question with your update?

Comment: @nope, question still the same:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You didn't specify to which program you wanted to send the signal.
2. You sent the signals before setting the handlers!
3. You're missing "`sub`".

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

$SIG{USR1} = sub { print `dd if=/def/zero of=/dev/null bs=512`; };
$SIG{USR2} = sub { print `free -m`; };
$SIG{INT}  = sub { kill USR1 => $$; die "Interrupt"; };

kill USR1 => $$;
kill USR2 => $$;
```

---

Also,

1. `` print `...` `` is a silly way of writing `system('...')`.
2. Don't send a signal to call a function!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

sub job1 { system('dd if=/def/zero of=/dev/null bs=512'); }
sub job2 { system('free -m'); }

$SIG{USR1} = \&job1;
$SIG{USR2} = \&job2;
$SIG{INT}  = sub { job1(); die "Interrupt"; };

kill USR1 => $$;
kill USR2 => $$;
```

Comment: `print \`...\`` has the advantage that the Perl process is doing the printing instead of the child process, and can easily be changed to just `\`...\`` once debugging is complete

Comment: It might also be worth looking at the [sigtrap](https://metacpan.org/pod/sigtrap) pragma on CPAN.

Comment: @Borodin, I think you mean `print \`...\`` has the *disadvantage* that the Perl process is doing the printing instead of the child process? My answer already points that out. `system('...')` is far less wasteful.

Comment: @Borodin, There's no indication that the print part of `print \`...\`` is there for debugging purpose, and every indication that it's actual code. If the `print` was debugging code, the value returned by the backticks would have been saved.